# How to get Debug and Profile window in EA 10

Tags: c#, uml

I have recently installed **trial version** of `EA 10`. Some how i close Debug and profile window.
I am not able to figure out that option in Tool. Please tell me the shortcut for Debug and *profile window* in `EA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profiler have no shortcut. But you can create it. Go to the toolbar, rightclick it, choose Customize at the bottom, get Keyboard tab, choose category - analyzer, find profiler in the list and set a key for it. After that, launch it.

As for Debugger, it could be launched so: rightclick on toolbar - > toolbars - turn on Debug.